# A linear operator is closed if and only if it is weak-weak continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, unbounded-operators

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces. I want to show that $A: \text{Dom}(A) \subseteq X \rightarrow Y$ is a closed linear operator if and only if for $x_n \in \text{Dom}(A)$ with $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ and $Ax_n \rightharpoonup y$ we have $x \in \text{Dom}(A)$ and $Ax = y$. Here "$\rightharpoonup$" denotes weak convergence.

The $\Leftarrow$ direction is straightforward because strong convergence implies weak convergence. But I couldn't come up with an argument for $\Rightarrow$ direction. Suppose $A$ is closed, which is equivalent to the fact that $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $Ax_n \rightarrow y$ implies $Ax = y$. Now assume $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ and $Ax_n \rightharpoonup y$. We need to show $x \in \text{Dom}(A)$ and $Ax = y$. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Show that $(x_n,Ax_n)$ converges to $(x,y)$ in the weak topology on the product space $X\times Y$.  Then use [Mazur's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%27s_lemma).

Comment: @JohnDoe Perfect comment!! See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanis%C5%82aw_Mazur) part Lwow and Warsaw

Comment: @JohnDoe Thanks for the comment. Now that I have $(x_n,Ax_n) \rightharpoonup (x,y)$. By Mazur's lemma, there exists a sequence consisting of convex combinations of $(x_n,Ax_n)$ that converges strongly to $(x,y)$. Please forgive my ignorance, but I don't see why this gives $Ax=y$. I wasn't able to extract a relation between $Ax$ and $y$ in the strong convergence. Could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: @Chris: $A$ is linear so a convex combination is $(v_n, Av_n)$ for some other sequence for which $v_n\in\operatorname{Dom}(A)$.